# How to use the same gravity form ID multiple times on the same page

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

The page setup that I have at the moment is that I have a gravity form that caters for event registration. In this form I have a hidden field that tells me which event the use has registered for.

I display multiple event registrations on one page, so I use the same form multiple times on the same page, but each one with a different "event_name" value.

The problem I'm having is that because each form has the same id, once they submit a registration for one event, all the forms show the "thank you" message and don't allow a resubmit.

Ideally I would like them to not be able to resubmit, but still be able to submit the forms for the other events.

The events are dynamically created, so I can't have a specific form for each event.

Any ideas would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar and simply used the conditional part of Gravity Forms.  This way, you don't display the form multiple times, but you only show certain fields after they tell you what event they are registering for.

Comment: I wonder, could you provide some more detail about how you configured the conditional part of Gravity Forms, to accomplish this?